# What is the correct process of using UFW + Nginx + Lets Encrpyt + Streamlit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, streamlit

I'm very new to server config so please excuse me if I don't explain something properly.

My current stack is Ubuntu 18.04 with Certbot, Nginx, and a Streamlit application all in separate Docker containers. Certbot is handling Letsencrypt ssl certificates for port 443, Nginx is using a reverse proxy on port 80 to my Streamlit application on port 8501. Streamlit natively uses port 8501.

I want to config everything so that I don't have port 8501 accessible. So my current site is https://joeysapps.com but someone could easily go to http://198.58.107.80:8501/ .

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    command: streamlit run app.py
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx_app
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - app
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot_app
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

My Streamlit App's DockerFile looks like this:

```
# base image
FROM python:3.7

# streamlit-specific commands
RUN mkdir -p /root/.streamlit
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[general]\n\
email = \"\"\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/credentials.toml'
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[server]\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml'

# copy over and install packages
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install cython
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY main.cae71b2a.chunk.js /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/static/static/js/

# copying everything over
COPY . .
```

My Nginx conf looks like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name joeysapps.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }   

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name joeysapps.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/joeysapps.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/joeysapps.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8501/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

}
```

When I use the Docker command: Docker ps I get this:

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:8501->8501/tcp, :::8501->8501/tcp
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp
80/tcp, 443/tcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the port publicly accessible then remove this line from your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
```

When you do this, docker binds port 8501 of the host to 8501 of the `app` container. [See more info about ports directive.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Since you are starting all services inside the same project, they will (be default) create a private network all the containers can communicate on.

You then want to also modify the following from your `nginx.conf`:

```
    location / {
        # proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8501/;
        
        # Use the name of the container. 
        # The docker network will perform DNS resolution for you.
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/;
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll give it a try asap.

Comment: Update: I tried it and nginx gave me a bad gateway. I'm going to keep trying and see.

Comment: Maybe try the `expose` directive. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose. Just list port 8501 there and see if you are able to hit your app.

Comment: It worked! I'm an idiot and didn't reboot the server. But it only worked when I expose "8501" rather then removing the port config completely. Thanks a million!!

Comment: No problem! I'll update my answer for future reference